# Как переопределить методы внутреннего класса?

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Есть класс с внутренними классами:

```
public class ParentClass  {

    //состояние объекта
    public class State  {
        public void action(){}
    }  
    public State currentState;
    public void setState(int stateID)  {
        if(stateID==0) currentState = new Born();
        if(stateID==1) currentState = new Life();
        if(stateID==2) currentState = new Dead();
    }  

    //виды состояний
    public class Born extends State    {
        @Overide
        public void action(){}
    }
    public class Life extends State  {
        @Overide
        public void action(){}
    }
    public class Dead extends State  {}
        @Overide
        public void action(){}
    }

    ///уделяем объекту внимание
    public void Action  (){
        currentState.action();
    } 
}
```

Как переопределить в наследнике методы внутренних классов Born Life и Dead, без наследования самих классов?

```
Задумка была простой  
1. Обеспечить каждого наследника своей реализацией методов action(). 
2. Оставить метод переключений состояния объекта setState() в родителе.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, имелось в виде что-то подобное:

```
public class ParentClass {

    public State currentState;

    public void setState(int stateID) {
        if (stateID == 0) currentState = new Born() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                // action for Born state
            }
        };

        if (stateID == 1) currentState = new Life() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                // action for Life state
            }
        };

        if (stateID == 2) currentState = new Dead() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                // action for Dead state
            }
        };
    }

    //состояние объекта
    public class State {
        public void action() {
        }
    }

    //виды состояний
    public class Born extends State {
    }

    public class Life extends State {
    }

    public class Dead extends State {

        ///уделяем объекту внимание
        public void Action() {
            currentState.action();
        }
    }
}
```

Или вообще так:

```
public class ParentClass {

    public State currentState;

    public void setState(int stateID) {
        if (stateID == 0) currentState = new State() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                // action for Born state
            }
        };

        if (stateID == 1) currentState = new State() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                // action for Life state
            }
        };

        if (stateID == 2) currentState = new State() {
            @Override
            public void action() {
                // action for Dead state
            }
        };
    }

    ///уделяем объекту внимание
    public void Action() {
        currentState.action();
    }

    //состояние объекта
    public class State {
        public void action() {
        }
    }
}
```

Но вообще, паттерн `State` немного по-другому лучше реализовать.

Comment: У вас тоже наследование ;)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил в ответ без наследования вообще. Но думаю, автор имел в виду что-то другое...

Comment: задумка была такая: setState() оставить в родителе без изменений, тк знаем все его известные состояния.(Born Life Dead). А реализацию методов этих состояний отдать наследникам.

Comment: в Ваших вариантах метод setState() придется переопределять в наследнике, но решение нахожу очень интересным.

Comment: Спасибо. А как бы Вы реализовали паттерн State?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець конструкция `new State() {}` это всё равно наследование, хоть и менее явное. Но вариант хороший.

Comment: Согласен вариант 2 красивый, лучше чем мой, поскольку гибче и не ограничивает наследников количеством состояний. Автору спасибо!!! Я б в жизь не до пёр:)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    class ChildInner extends ParentClass.ClassBorn {
        public void action() {}
    }
}
```

И в вашем примере не локальные классы, а внутренние.

Comment: возможно ли переопределение методов внутренних классов, без наследования самих внутренних классов?

Comment: Нет, невозможно.

Comment: возможно я не правильно изложил проблему, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Мой ответ от этого не меняется, вы не можете переопределять методы вложенных классов, не наследуя их.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, так просили же без наследования...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець что изначально просили можно посмотреть в истории правок.

Comment: спасибо за правки в определениях.

Comment: Никоим образом не хочу никого обидеть, просто возбудился на слово невозможно. По моему мнению нет ничего невозможного, есть только лень и потеря гибкости ума.

Comment: @user9232557 а ещё есть технические ограничения. Как бы вы не были трудолюбивы и гибки умом, вам не создать массив обобщённых типов, например.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev. Есть параметрический полиморфизм, его java поддерживает. Он вполне подходит для обработки объектов обобщённых типов. А ссылки на объекты можно хранить в любых массивах Object[] arrayAll = new Object[n];

Comment: @user9232557 для инженера важно понимать лимиты систем, с которыми он работает. Отказ их замечать или попытки их обходить не сделают из вас хорошего специалиста.

Comment: @Hivemaster. Все зависит от приоритета задачи. При должном мотивироваНИИ поднять лимит системы вопрос времени.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы я реализовал шаблон `State`

```
public interface MotorState {
    void on(Motor motor);
    void off(Motor motor);
}
```

2 состояния, например, включен и выключен:

```
public class MotorOn implements MotorState {

    @Override
    public void on(Motor motor) {
        System.out.println("Motor is already on");
    }

    @Override
    public void off(Motor motor) {
        motor.setState(new MotorOff());
        System.out.println("Motor is off");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Motor is on";
    }
}

public class MotorOff implements MotorState {

    @Override
    public void on(Motor motor) {
        motor.setState(new MotorOn());
        System.out.println("Motor is on");
    }

    @Override
    public void off(Motor motor) {
        System.out.println("Motor is already off");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Motor is off";
    }
}
```

Сам мотор:

```
public class Motor {
    private MotorState state;

    public Motor() {
        this.state = new MotorOff();
    }

    public MotorState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(MotorState newState) {
        this.state = newState;
    }

    public void turnOn() {
        state.on(this);
    }

    public void turnOff() {
        state.off(this);
    }

    public boolean isOn() {
        return state instanceof MotorOn;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Интересно.